# How to associate DelegatingHandler to specific HttpClient?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following interface and classes (implementation left out for brevity):

```cs
public interface ITokenAuthenticationService { ... }

public class TokenAuthenticationService(
    IOptions<TokenOptions> options,
    HttpClient httpClient,
    TimeProvider? timeProvider = null
) : ITokenAuthenticationService
{ ... }

public class TokenDelegatingHandler(
    ITokenAuthenticationService tokenAuthenticationService
) : DelegatingHandler
{ ... }

public class MyService1(HttpClient client)
{ ... }
```

In my program:

```cs
var sp = new ServiceCollection()
    .Configure<TokenOptions>(configuration.GetRequiredSection("Service1"))
    .AddTransient<TokenDelegatingHandler>()
    .AddHttpClient<ITokenAuthenticationService, TokenAuthenticationService>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://auth.service1.com")).Services

    // Service 1
    .AddHttpClient<MyService1>()
        .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://service1.com"))
        .AddHttpMessageHandler<TokenDelegatingHandler>().Services
        .BuildServiceProvider();
        
var bar = sp.GetRequiredService<MyService1>();
var result = await bar.DoSomethingAsync("baz");
```

The `TokenAuthenticationService` needs some options to work correctly. Now:

How would I set this up so I can use a second service (`MyService2`) to use another `TokenDelegatingHandler` with different settings for the second service? I'm not sure how I associate the correct `TokenDelegatingHandler` to the correct HttpClient (without inheriting from TokenDelegatingHandler and making a `Service1TokenDelegatingHandler` and `Service2TokenDelegatingHandler` or something).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because different `TokenAuthenticationService`, `TokenOptions` and `HttpClient` instances can co-exist each with different settings, you need a keyed/named setup.

Since you're on .NET 8 - your code shows the usage of primary constructors - you can use the combination of

- [keyed services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#keyed-services) - this one is new for NET 8
- [named HTTP clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#named-clients)
- [named options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-8.0#named-options-support-using-iconfigurenamedoptions)

Since all `MyService1` instances will have a similar configuration, you can set it up as a [typed HTTP client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-8.0#typed-clients). But for its `TokenDelegatingHandler` you need a keyed/named retrieval.

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyService1>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(o => o.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://service1.com"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(
        sp => new TokenDelegatingHandler(
            sp.GetRequiredKeyedService<ITokenAuthenticationService>("service1-tokenhandler")
    ));
```

Register the `ITokenAuthenticationService` for the `DelegatingHandler` of `MyService1` with a known key.

```
services.AddKeyedTransient<ITokenAuthenticationService, TokenAuthenticationService>(
    "service1-tokenhandler",
    (sp, key) => new TokenAuthenticationService(
        sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<TokenOptions>>().Get("tokenservice1-options"),
        sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("tokenservice1-client"),
        sp.GetService<TimeProvider>()
    ));
```

Or you can do above setup without a named/keyed approach as shown below.

```
services.AddHttpClient<MyService1>()
    .ConfigureHttpClient(o => o.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://service1.com"))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler(sp =>
        new TokenDelegatingHandler(
            new TokenAuthenticationService(
                sp.GetRequiredService<IOptionsMonitor<TokenOptions>>().Get("tokenservice1-options"),
                sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("tokenservice1-client"),
                sp.GetService<TimeProvider>()
    )));
```

Register the named `HttpClient` and settings/options of that `ITokenAuthenticationService` for `MyService1`.
The settings file (e.g. `Appsettings.json`) should hold a section with a path/key matching the one used for the settings/options (here: `tokenservice1-options-section`).

```
services.AddHttpClient("tokenservice1-client")
    .ConfigureHttpClient(o => o.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://auth.service1.com"));

services.Configure<TokenOptions>("tokenservice1-options",
    configuration.GetSection("tokenservice1-options-section"));
// or:
// services.AddOptions<TokenOptions>("tokenservice1-options")
//     .BindConfiguration("tokenservice1-options-section");
```

---

Because the named options are being retrieved via [`IOptionsMonitor`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptionsmonitor-1?view=dotnet-plat-ext-8.0), the `TokenAuthenticationService` takes a `TokenOptions` instead of a `IOptions<TokenOptions>`.

```
public class TokenAuthenticationService(
    TokenOptions options,
    HttpClient httpClient, TimeProvider? timeProvider = null
    ) : ITokenAuthenticationService
{ }
```

---

For `MyService2` it looks similar, just some different names/keys and urls.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive reply! I'm currently enjoying my weekend after a long week but I'll try this monday first thing! Thanks!

Comment: Works like a charm. Sorry it took me so long to accept the answer.